# Producing ICE plot in R from the ICEbox package

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to produce an ICE plot from the ICEbox package in R, based on the sample code from [plot.ice examples](https://rdrr.io/cran/ICEbox/man/plot.ice.html) However I am getting errors.

I am using a random forest model from the caret package, as can be seen below. There are 1,118 predictor variables and a response variable, "grp".

```
library(caret)
control <- trainControl(method="cv",
                    number=5,
                    summaryFunction = prSummary,
                    classProbs = T)

mtry <- sqrt(ncol(train[,2:1020]))

rf_fit <- train(grp~.,
            data=train[,2:1020],
            method="rf",
            metric="AUC",
            tuneGrid=expand.grid(.mtry=mtry),
            trControl=control,
            importance=TRUE,
            ntree = 200)
```

When creating an ICE object with the predictor variable, "ageardiagnosis" using the code below I get an error.

```
age.ice = ice(object = rf_fit, X = train[,2:1020], 
              predictor = "ageatdiagnosis", frac_to_build = .1)
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error in ice(object = rf_fit, X = train[, 2:1019], y = train$grp, 
predictor = "ageatdiagnosis",  : 
Do not pass y when it is categorical variable.
```

When I don't pass y using the following code:

```
age.ice = ice(object = rf_fit, X = train[,2:1020], predictor = 
"ageatdiagnosis",frac_to_build = .1)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in ice(object = rf_fit, X = train[, 2:1020], predictor = 
"ageatdiagnosis",  : 
The predict function must return probabilities (not levels of a factor).
```

Should I input the predicted probabilities? The example listed here doesn't seem to suggest so [plot.ice examples](https://rdrr.io/cran/ICEbox/man/plot.ice.html).

I would use the pdp package instead but I am using RStudio on a server which only has R version 3.2.3.

Comment: For `ICEbox` package the function examples can not be reproduced. I advise reporting on [github](https://github.com/kapelner/ICEbox)

Comment: Is there any othere packages other than ICEbox or pdp that can produce ICE plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the reference manual for the ICEbox package I was able to find a solution to the problem. The issue was that the above examples were for a regression problem while mine was a classification problem.

An example for a classification problem can be found here: [ICEbox Reference Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ICEbox/ICEbox.pdf).

The working code for my problem can be found below:

```
y = train$grp
X = train
X$grp = NULL

rf_age.ice = ice(object = pima_rf, X = X, predictor = "ageatdiagnosis", 
                 logodds = TRUE,
                 predictfcn = function(object, newdata){
                     predict(object, newdata, type = "prob")[,2]
                 }
)

plot(rf_age.ice)
```